# Autolayout with dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to create a subclass of UIView that will show a list of fixed sized UIImages similar to how a UILabel displays letters.
If all the images won't fit on one line, the images are arranged on multiple lines.

How can I achieve this using autolayouts so that if I put this view in a UIStackView the images will be listed correctly?

Here is a sample if I did it using fixed position :

```
- (void) layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    for (UIImageView* imageView in self.imageViews){
        imageView.frame = imageRect;
        imageRect.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(imageRect);
        if (CGRectGetMaxX(imageRect) > CGRectGetMaxX(bounds)){
            imageRect.origin.x = 0.0;
            imageRect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(imageRect);
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
Here is a sample project to show the issue.
https://github.com/datinc/DATDemoImageListView

Here the link for ImageListView
https://github.com/datinc/DATDemoImageListView/blob/master/DATDemoImageListView/DATDemoImageListView.m

Comment: How about using UICollectionView?

Comment: You should turn of `translatesAutoresizingMaskintoContraints` for the image views.

Comment: @datinc if you are using using `autoLayout` then use `constraints` to change the height/width of your view. And add the `imageViews` in `awakeFromNib` or `init` method as you may know that `layoutSubviews` is called multiple times.

Comment: @Adell, I added a sample project. Can you make a pull request explaining what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

<del>You should overwrite [intrinsicContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize?language=objc) returning the preferred content size of your view.</del>

The problem is that in `intrinsicContentSize` the view has not it's final bounds. You can use an internal height constraint, and overwrite `updateConstraints`:

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    CGFloat theWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);
    NSUInteger theCount = [self.subviews count];
    CGFloat theRows = ceilf(theCount / floorf(theWidth / 30.0));

    self.heightConstraint.constant = 30.0 * theRows;
    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

In `viewDidAppear:` and on layout changes (e. g. rotation) you have to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` to get a proper initial layout of the image views.

Comment: intrinsicContentSize does not let me update the height. Using intrinsicContentSize the view will always be only one line high

Comment: How do you have implemented it? For enhancing the clarity `intrinsincContentSize`never updates the size. Autolayout asks the view for its favourite size, and selects the size which is fitting best. There are some other parameters (e. g. hugging and stretching priorities) influencing the size.

Comment: The way I would implement it would be
return CGSize(self.image.count * 30, 30);

Comment: So, `intrinsicContentSize` works fine, because you return always a height of one row. ;) But you can nearly reuse your code above to compute a multi-row content size.

Comment: The issue is that the UIStackView does not know the height that the view should be. intrinsicContentSize assumes unlimited width/height.

Comment: Added a sample project

Comment: When I added your code to the sample project, "theWidth" is 0.0. So I still cannot set the height.